# A question about nonabelian finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a nonabelian finite simple group of lie type on finite field $F$ and $s\in G$ be a semisimpl element of $G$, $i.e.$ an element with order coprime to $Char(F)$. Also suppose $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$ containing $s$. Is it true that $T\subseteq C_G(s)$ where $C_G(s)=\{g\in G:~sg=gs\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any torus, in particular any maximal torus is by definition an abelian subgroup. So the answer is yes, and the assumption about $s$ being semisimple is not needed.

Comment: But is it not true that all elements of tori are semisimple?

Comment: @ Derek: I don't know why your comment is true! Can you introduce any reference? Even more what is the definition of torus?! I thought, that it is a subgroup of $G$ containing semisimple elements and identity. In Carter's book (Finite groups of lie  type, conjugacy classes and compact characters, p.15) have been asserted that $G_s=\bigcup_{T~is~a~torus}T$ where $G$ is a solvable group and $G_S$ is its closed subgroup containing semisimple elements and identity. But why it is not true for other groups?

Comment: I was asking a question not making a statement!

Comment: Oh, sorry! You are right.

Comment: @Adeleh: The definition I know is the same as the one on wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus "A torus in a compact Lie group $G$ is a compact, connected, abelian Lie subgroup of $G$ (and therefore isomorphic to the standard torus Tn). A maximal torus is one which is maximal among such subgroups."